# ayuda con error de iis

Tags: webservice, iis

Alguien por favor podría colaborarme con este problema que tengo en la publicación de un Servicio web asmx desarrollado en vs2015? el servidor es WS2012R2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola RSillerico, agrega tu Web.config por favor.

Answer (score 0):

me parece que haces referencia a otra versión de Framework que probablemente no tienes instalada, asegura que la versión 4.0 este instalada y cambia el `targetFramework` a 4.0 en tu Web.config:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
```